# Matplotlib with ultrasonic sensor using Arduino

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino

I want to plot data received from ultrasonic sensor. I am able to do it but having trouble with the group. Like if the plotted value is 147 and if the next value I am getting is 10, it gets plotted above 147 and not below it.

```
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ser = serial.Serial("COM3", baudrate=9600,timeout=1)
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()



x, y = list(), list()

i = 0

while True:
    ser.write(b'u')
    data = ser.readline()
    pri_data = data.decode("ascii")

    x.append(i)
    y.append(data.decode())
    plt.plot(x,y)
    i += 1
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
    print(pri_data)
```

Comment: What happens if you plot(y,x)? Maybe you have axes confused

Comment: I tried that but the axis changed...still the problem was the same about x-axis

Comment: Could I see your graph it may be more helpful